# Comparing strings of json in tests

Tags: json, kotlin

```
var jsonString = """"{"opt_value":"IN"}""""

my jsonstring  :""{"ID_value":"IN"}""
What the test is returning   :"{"ID_value":"IN"}"
```

I can't seem to get my JSON to compare. am I missing something here? testing locally in postman shows to me that I return

```
{
    "ID_value": "IN"
}
```

Comment: the expected one seems invalid json.

Comment: Looks like `jsonString` should be `"""{"opt_value":"IN"}"""` (too many double quotes)

Comment: @akoz did not seem to work 

i returned

expected:<""{"opt_value":"IN"}""> but was:<"{"opt_value":"IN"}">
Expected :""{"opt_value":"IN"}""
Actual   :"{"opt_value":"IN"}"

Comment: Why does this question have java, spring-boot and kotlin tags?

Comment: @LeiYang yeah i can't seem to create a variable that matches the expected JSON

Comment: search for *java json compare*

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to remove a quote at the beginning and the end, like

```
var jsonString = """{"opt_value":"IN"}"""
```